# C++ Constant parameter of a class

Tags: c++, qt

I'm implementing custom TableModel (`MyTableModel` class) in Qt, based on `QAbstractTableModel` to display the data stored in an object of `MyDataStorage` class. It requires defining `rowCount()` and `columnCount()` functions for `MyTableModel`.

In my case I have a class `MyDataStorage` that contains a `QList<MyData> dataList`. `MyData` class consists of a five member variables (one `int`, one `QDate` and three `QString`s).
`MyTableModel::rowCount()` returns simply the length of `MyDataStorage`'s `dataList`.
`MyTableModel::columnCount()` must return the number of members of `MyData` that are to be shown in the table, so first I defined the public method `MyData::getParameterCount() {return 5;}`, so that I could use it as shown below:

```
class MyTableModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    MyDataStorage& im;
public:
    explicit InfoTableModel(MyDataStorage& m, QObject *parent = 0);
    int rowCount();
    inline int columnCount() {return m.getLast().getParameterCount()};
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const;
//...
}
```

I feel it is not the best solution as the list can be empty. Other possibilites are to define:

- equivalent function in `MyDataStorage`,
- preprocessor constant,
- static member of `MyData`,
- simple `inline int columnCount() {return 5;}` as `MyTableModel` has to be changed with every change of the underlying data model (it's the most obvious solution, but I'm scared if this is correct)

but I don't feel any of them is the proper solution, as the number of `MyData` members will change in the future.

What are your propositions?

Comment: There was my mistake. I edited the post. The `getLast` method of `MyDataStorage` simply returns the last data appended to the list: `MyDataStorage::getLast() {return dataList.last()}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare `MyData::getParameterCount()` as `static` member and then refer to it like this:

```
inline int columnCount() const {return MyData::getParameterCount();}
```

In that case you don't need any `MyData` objects.

Comment: Thanks @dmitry-markin! I did it this way. In your solution I do not have to initialize the static member outside the class.

Comment: Is the `inline` necessary in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have an element in your storage, then your row count is zero, as is your column count. Therefore you should just check this:

```
inline int columnCount() { return (m.isEmpty() ? 0 : m.getLast().getParameterCount()) };
```